# ViewPager with Swipe and clickable view inside

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I am following a tutorial from [medium](https://medium.com/@jimitpatel/viewpager-with-vertical-swiping-ability-e40200094281) to create Vertical View pager and it works perfectly. Below is the code for the same:

```
public class CustomViewPager extends ViewPager {
public static final int HORIZONTAL = 0;
public static final int VERTICAL = 1;

private int mSwipeOrientation;
private ScrollerCustomDuration mScroller = null;

public CustomViewPager(Context context) {
    super(context);
    mSwipeOrientation = HORIZONTAL;
}

public CustomViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    setSwipeOrientation(context, attrs);
}

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (mSwipeOrientation == VERTICAL) {
        boolean intercepted = super.onInterceptHoverEvent(swapXY(event));
        swapXY(event);
        return intercepted;
    }
    return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    return super.onTouchEvent(mSwipeOrientation == VERTICAL ? swapXY(event) : event);
}

public void setSwipeOrientation(int swipeOrientation) {
    if (swipeOrientation == HORIZONTAL || swipeOrientation == VERTICAL)
        mSwipeOrientation = swipeOrientation;
    else
        throw new IllegalStateException("Swipe Orientation can be either CustomViewPager.HORIZONTAL" +
                " or CustomViewPager.VERTICAL");
    initSwipeMethods();
}

private void setSwipeOrientation(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    TypedArray typedArray = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.CustomViewPager);
    mSwipeOrientation = typedArray.getInteger(R.styleable.CustomViewPager_swipe_orientation, 0);
    typedArray.recycle();
    initSwipeMethods();
}

private void initSwipeMethods() {
    if (mSwipeOrientation == VERTICAL) {
        // The majority of the work is done over here
        setPageTransformer(true, new VerticalPageTransformer());
        // The easiest way to get rid of the overscroll drawing that happens on the left and right
        setOverScrollMode(OVER_SCROLL_NEVER);
    }
}

/**
 * Set the factor by which the duration will change
 */
public void setScrollDurationFactor(double scrollFactor) {
    mScroller.setScrollDurationFactor(scrollFactor);
}

private MotionEvent swapXY(MotionEvent event) {
    float width = getWidth();
    float height = getHeight();

    float newX = (event.getY() / height) * width;
    float newY = (event.getX() / width) * height;

    event.setLocation(newX, newY);
    return event;
}

private class VerticalPageTransformer implements ViewPager.PageTransformer {

    @Override
    public void transformPage(@NonNull View page, float position) {
        if (position < -1) {
            // This page is way off-screen to the left
            page.setAlpha(0);
        } else if (position <= 1) {
            page.setAlpha(1);

            // Counteract the default slide transition
            page.setTranslationX(page.getWidth() * -position);

            // set Y position to swipe in from top
            float yPosition = position * page.getHeight();
            page.setTranslationY(yPosition);
        } else {
            // This page is way off screen to the right
            page.setAlpha(0);
        }
    }
}

@Override
protected boolean canScroll(final View v, final boolean checkV, final int dx, final int x, final int y) {
    if (v instanceof SubsamplingScaleImageView) {
        SubsamplingScaleImageView imageViewTouch = (SubsamplingScaleImageView)v;
        return true;
    } else {
        return super.canScroll(v, checkV, dx, x, y);
    }
}
```

The problem occurs when I have a clickable Image view as only view in item. My Scroll functionality will not work if the view is clickable. Also I recently started showing Mopub ads and even making Image non clickable my view will stop swiping when ad is shown and will always take click events only.

How to intercept touch and swipe gesture in viewpager

Answer (score 0):

Got it working. Was making a small mistake instead of this code

```
  boolean intercepted = super.onInterceptHoverEvent(swapXY(event));
```

You need to write

```
  boolean intercepted = super.onInterceptTouchEvent(swapXY(event));
```